# Highlighting text in an epub using Sigil and python

Tags: sigil, programming

This is a follow-up to

[Programming Sigil for importing annotations](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/programming-sigil-for-importing-annotations)

The answer there suggests to read the [Sigil Plugin Framework documentation](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/raw/master/docs/Sigil_Plugin_Framework_rev8.epub). Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to do the following.

My workflow would be to search for the annotated string in the epub and enclose it in `span` tags:

```
smart description of a topic
```

would become

```
<span class="highlight">smart description of a topic<>
```

and I would include

```
span.highlight { background: #ccc }
```

in the CSS part of the ebook.

What parts of the `BookContainer` class should I use to implement this and how?

Comment: You might want to post your question in the official [Sigil Plugin Development thread](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=268).

You also might want to download and run the [official test plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=267539).
It contains all the code fragments that you'll need for your plugin.